# split javascript string using a regexp to separate numbers from other characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

so for example:

`"10.cm"` ...becomes... `[10,".cm"]` or `["10",".cm"]`, either will do as I can work with a string once it's split up.

i tried

```
"10.cm".split(/[0-9]/|/[abc]/)
```

but it seems that i don't have such a great understanding of using regexp's

thanks

Comment: `str.match(/(\d+)(\D+)/`

Comment: thanks, seems to do the job

Comment: Does that mean you need `["10",".cm"]`?

Comment: either will do as i can work with a string once it's split up

Comment: is it always the same character the string needs to be splitted at?

Comment: ideally so i could split say "abc123hj45.f" into ["abc","123","hj","45",".f"]    so it splits it whenever the character type changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may tokenize the string into digits and non-digits with `/\d+|\D+/g` regex:

```js
var s = "10.cm";
console.log(s.match(/\d+|\D+/g));
```

**Details**:

- `\d+` - matches 1 or more digits
- `|` - or
- `\D+` - matches 1 or more characters other than digits.

Comment: Nice; I got lost in the details, trying to figure out how to make split do the job (which it almost can, but not with javascript regex), and didn't think about just using match instead...

Comment: When you need to split so as to keep all the characters there are in the string, *matching* is most likely what you need. Not always, but in this case, matching is really easier.

Comment: how would i write it if i just wanted to keep the decimal with the numbers
so "10.10cm" became ["10.10", "cm"]?

Comment: There are so many float regexps around here, here is a version I like most `/\d*\.?\d+|\D+/g`

Answer (score 0):

**/\W/** Matches any non-word character. This includes spaces and punctuation, but not underscores. In this solution can be used **/\W/** with split and join methods. You can separate numbers from other characters.

```
let s = "10.cm";
console.log(s.split(/\W/).join(" "));
```

output = 10 cm